# how to calculate summation with zero upper and lower boundaries?

Tags: summation

Can i evaluate this if both upper and lower boundaries turn out to be zero?!!

[image]

does it have a value or should i just disard it during calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^0 a_i = a_0$$ by definition, because by definition

$$\sum_{i=0}^na_i = \begin{cases}a_0 & n=0\\
a_n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i & n\geq 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: so i should just set the counter to zero and evaluate the inside summation!!